# Android Java Text to Speech Viewing Extra String Information

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I've been running through many of the text to speech examples available for Android and I have an issue that I assume is really simple, but I cannot for the life of me work it out!

I simply want to be able to view the output of EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES (for example) which according to [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.Engine.html#EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES) is returned in an ArrayList. There are many examples of how to deal with such output programmatically, but for the benefit of my learning and understanding, I want to see the actual returned data for myself.

My project is set up exactly as the android developers example [from here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TtsEngine/src/com/example/android/ttsengine/CheckVoiceData.html)

```
    // We now return the list of available and unavailable voices
    // as well as the return code.
    Intent returnData = new Intent();
    returnData.putStringArrayListExtra(
            TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES, available);
    returnData.putStringArrayListExtra(
            TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_UNAVAILABLE_VOICES, unavailable);
    setResult(result, returnData);
    finish();
}
```

Ideally I'd like to have the output displayed after the 'constant value' in a simple TextView from a string, but I can't achieve that, neither can I get it in a ListView despite my many efforts... Please can someone help me solve this!

Once I know how to view the returned data, I can then go on to follow the examples of how to deal with it correctly.

- I've not included any the code I've already tried, as I can't find an example anywhere and it's been pure guess work (which I be embarrassed to show!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is ever stuck with the same thing, I used the code below, edited from the sample found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/Handlerdifferentlanguages.htm):

```
    ArrayList<String> available = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra("availableVoices");
        Log.v("languages count", String.valueOf(available.size()));
        Iterator<String> iter = available.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String lang = iter.next();
            Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
            Log.v(TAG, "language: " + lang);
            Log.v(TAG, "language locale: " + locale.toString());

            TextView LocaleResults = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
                    R.id.textViewConfig);
            LocaleResults.append("\nAvailable Engine Language: " + lang);

        }

        ArrayList<String> unavailable = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra("unavailableVoices");
        Log.v("languages count", String.valueOf(unavailable.size()));
        Iterator<String> iteru = unavailable.iterator();
        while (iteru.hasNext()) {
            String ulang = iteru.next();
            Locale ulocale = new Locale(ulang);
            Log.v(TAG, "ulanguage: " + ulang);
            Log.v(TAG, "ulanguage locale: " + ulocale.toString());

            TextView LocaleResults = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
                    R.id.textViewConfig);
            LocaleResults.append("\nUnavailable Engine Language: " + ulang);

        }
```