# EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES is null. Why?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my application's main activity I issue an Intent with `ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

When it returns, in onActivityResult(), I try to list the available voices:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
        String availableVoices = intent.getStringExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);
        Log.d("TTS engine installed", "Available voices: " + availableVoices);
        new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }
  }
}
```

I *am* receiving `CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS` and everything works fine but according to the Log.d() message, `intent.getStringExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES)` returns null!

I know that there are quite a few voices in my phone, installed and working properly, so **why** does `getStringExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES)` return null?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES list using `getStringExtra()` instead of [getStringArrayListExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String%29).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993742/1124861) for more details.