# queryIntentActivities() data Intent extras

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My aim is to get the available TTS voice engines and their respective [available languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993742/1256219). I can successfully get the available engines with the following code:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    Intent ttsIntent = new Intent();
    ttsIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    // ttsIntent.getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);

    ArrayList<String> engineInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(ttsIntent,
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ResolveInfo appInfo : list) {
        engineInfo.add(appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
        engineInfo.add(appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                .toString());
    }
```

The commented out line above requests a data extra for the intent. I've done many searches, but can find no examples of `queryIntentActivities()` using 'getExtra' or 'putExtra' in this way.

Can I therefore assume, that this isn't an option and I need to go back to read some basics somewhere of why this isn't possible!?

If I make any attempt to retrieve the data, I get a null pointer, even if I'm checking if it's `!=null` which is a little odd?

```
appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.metaData.getEtcEtc...
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

`postPutEXTRA:` API level is 9 so [getEngines()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.EngineInfo.html) isn't available to me, although that would involve initialising a tts object for each one, so not ideal anyway.

`postPutEDIT:` I tried the following within the loop to extract associated uid's, but it didn't work for all but one of the voice engines I tested.

```
    ApplicationInfo ai = null;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String[] voices = pm.getPackagesForUid(ai.uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through a similar process, but if I remember correctly, you can't simply fire of an intent query to get the available languages. That absolutely makes sense, because what languages are available depends on what voices and other packages the user will have installed with the TTS engine. In other words: it's not some static parameter that you query for, but requires to be resolved at runtime.

In order to get the available voices (and other information) for a TTS engine, you'll need to actually start/initialise it. That means you need to do something like:

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

And then retrieve the data in `onActivityResult(...)`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) return;
    // here you should be able to get the info from 'data', i.e.
    ArrayList<String> voices = getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);
}
```

Note that I copy-pasted most of above from an [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html) on the Android dev blog.

It's been a while since I last played with TTS, so if above doesn't work out, feel free to leave a comment and I'll have a closer look at the implementation I made back then.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That intent requires the user to manually select the voice engine though, the point of using queryIntentActivities was to generate a list without the user interaction. Sorry I didn't make this clear...

Comment: @andjav: Ah, sorry about missing that. I remember doing an attempt at backporting some of the new TTS functionality from ICS in order to make it available on older platforms, but unfortunately the logic from `getEngines()` (with `pm.queryIntentServices(new Intent(Engine.INTENT_ACTION_TTS_SERVICE),  PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)` being the key) did not appear to work on pre-ICS... If you ever find a workaround, I'll be very much interested in hearing so.

Comment: I've answered how I did this. I'm not sure it's the cleanest way, but it gets the result!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the specific title of this question, but I did get the information I wanted of the available voice engines and their languages on the device, without user interaction, in the following way:

```
private void getEngines() {

    Intent ttsIntent = new Intent();
    ttsIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);

    ArrayList<String> engineInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(ttsIntent,
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ResolveInfo appInfo : list) {
        engineInfo.add(appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);

        ttsIntent
                .setPackage(appInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
        ttsIntent
                .getStringArrayListExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_AVAILABLE_VOICES);

        startActivityForResult(ttsIntent, 33);

    }

    if (DE.BUG) {
        MyLog.d("engineInfo: " + engineInfo.size() + " : "
                + engineInfo.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 33 && data != null) {

        ArrayList<String> available = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra("availableVoices");

        if (DE.BUG) {
            MyLog.i("Voices: " + available.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I've left in my custom logging class/method to show where I'm capturing the data. You can rearrange the above to put all of the data into one or more global array list(s).